# JBOSS EAP6.4 and mod_cluster

Tags: jboss, mod-cluster

I want to set up clustering and fail-over system with one apache httpd and two JBOSS EAP 6.4.
[image: one apache and tow jboss eap 6.4]

1. download

   mod_cluster download

   http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-1-3

   jboss eap 6.4 download
   http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/
2. My httpd.config is like that:

   ```
       LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
       LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
       LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

   LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so

   LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
   LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so
   LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

   # MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS
   # Adjust to you hostname and subnet.
   <IfModule manager_module>
     Listen 192.168.0.195:6666
     ManagerBalancerName mycluster
     <VirtualHost 192.168.0.195:6666>
       <Location />
        Require ip 192.168.0.195
       </Location>

       KeepAliveTimeout 300
       MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
       #ServerAdvertise on http://127.0.0.1:6666
       AdvertiseFrequency 5
       #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
       #AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
       EnableMCPMReceive

       <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
          SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
          Order deny,allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from 192.168.0
       </Location>

     </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. I used default standalone-ha.xml
4. I ran the jboss like this:
   192.168.0.10:
   standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.node.name='node1'

   192.168.0.195:
   standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.node.name='node2'
5. In 192.168.0.10, mod_cluster manager is like that:

   [image]

Question)

1. Is my httpd.conf right?

2. If I use "standalone-ha.xml", is there any configuration for mod_cluster?

3. Is there any full-configuring guide with one apache and two jboss-eap-6.4?

Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** I must use mod_cluster-1.2.x with JBOSS EAP 6.x

```
1. mod_cluster download

    http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-2-6-Final-bin

2. unzip and install mod_cluster

    D:\httpd-2.2\bin>installconf.bat

3. edit httpd.conf

    127.0.0.1 -> local ip address
    (below image)

4.install EAP6.4

    download from http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/

    Nothing to configure.

5. run EAP6.4
requirements:
- balancing
- failover
- session replication
when using tcp for jgroups: at standalone-ha.xml (line:271 udp -> tcp )
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="tcp">

standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.168.0.10 -Djboss.node.name=node1
standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.168.0.195 -Djboss.node.name=node2

-b x.x.x.x: EAP6.4 IP( for standalone-xx.xml)
```

[image: http.conf]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the apache configuration.
But for JBoss you need to configure mod_cluster for the advertizing.
The configuration for the JBoss server is described within the administration guide:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Web_HTTP_Connectors_and_HTTP_Clustering.html

The cluster howto from the community documentation contains an example with apache and JBoss configuration:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/AS7+Cluster+Howto